# Array_rand and Implode output stuck

Tags: php

I have a problem output of array_rand with implode, and I've stuck for 2 days. Any help would appreciate.

```php
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

    $keys = array_keys($list); 
    shuffle($keys); 
    $random = array(); 
    foreach ($keys as $key) { 
        $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
    }
    return $random; 
} 

$keywords_array = array("car 1 "," car 2 "," car 3 "," car 4 "," car 5 "," car 5 "," car 6");
$frontword_list = array("Amazing", "Good-Looking", "Magnificent", "Pretty", "Sparkling", "Awesome", "Imaginative", "Outstanding");
$frontword_list = $frontword_list[array_rand($frontword_list)];
$preposition = array(" alongside "," amidst "," among ", " beside "," including ","  near ", " as well "," next to ", " within ");
$preposition_rand = $preposition[array_rand($preposition)];
$description = $frontword_list ." ". implode($preposition_rand, shuffle_assoc($keywords_array));
echo $description;
```

the output from the `$preposition_rand` it won't shuffle

```
Amazing car 2 next to car 6 next to car 5 next to car 3 next to car 5 next to car 1 next to car 4
```

What's the right code for shuffle the `$preposition_rand` output like

```
Amazing car 2 amidst car 6 including car 5 alongside car 3 beside car 5 near car 1 as well car 4
```

Comment: Implode takes a single string argument.  And uses it in all instances of the implosion --- hence the results you're getting.

It's kind of an interesting problem.  I wonder if you need array_reduce() and a custom callback function, or perhaps array_replace()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php

function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
}

//a new function that returns the string according to the requirements
function implode_array($prep,$keywords_arr) {
    $string = "";
    for ( $num = 0; $num < count($keywords_arr); $num++ ) {
        $random_index = rand(0,count($prep)-1); //set random number, random number does not exceed the length of $preposition
        if ( $num != count($keywords_arr)-1 ) {
            $string .= $keywords_arr[$num] . $prep[$random_index]; //insert preposition after keywords_array[$num] if keyword isn't last of array
        } else {
            $string .= $keywords_arr[$num]; //does not insert preposition after the last index in keywords_array
        }
        unset($prep[$random_index]); //unset used index
        $prep = array_values($prep); //reset index values
    }
    return $string;
}

$keywords_array = array("car 1 "," car 2 "," car 3 "," car 4 "," car 5 "," car 5 "," car 6");
$frontword_list = array("Amazing", "Good-Looking", "Magnificent", "Pretty", "Sparkling", "Awesome", "Imaginative", "Outstanding");
                    $frontword_list = $frontword_list[array_rand($frontword_list)];
                    $preposition = array(" alongside "," amidst "," among ", " beside "," including ","  near ", " as well "," next to ", " within ");
                    $description = $frontword_list ." ". implode_array($preposition,$keywords_array); //call the new function
                    echo $description;
```

This displays something like:

```
Outstanding car 1  next to  car 2  beside  car 3   near  car 4  amidst  car 5  as well  car 5  within  car 6
```

If you have more keywords_array than your preposition, you can just remove these lines:

```
unset($prep[$random_index]); //unset used index
$prep = array_values($prep); //reset index values
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me alot. I'm really appreciated

Comment: Hi, in your function  $random_index = rand(0,count($prep)-1); //set random number, random number does not exceed the length of $preposition, how do I set if the keyword_arr more than length of $preposition? says, if I have a keywords_arr more than 10 and the $preposition only 5, the output between keywords_arr number 6 till 10, there is no preposition? how do we fix that? once again thank you

Comment: You can fix that by removing unset($prep[$random_index]); //unset used index and $prep = array_values($prep); //reset index values

Comment: Yeah.. thank you, you saved my life again. I have to learn more about php. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I'm here to help :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion in this point you are using wrongly array_rand
$preposition_rand = $preposition[array_rand($preposition)];

Could you try something like this:

```
function join_list($a,$b){
  return "$a $b";
}

$keywords_array = array("car 1 "," car 2 "," car 3 "," car 4 "," car 5 "," car 5 "," car 6");
$frontword_list = array("Amazing", "Good-Looking", "Magnificent", "Pretty", "Sparkling", "Awesome", "Imaginative", "Outstanding");
$frontword_list = $frontword_list[array_rand($frontword_list)];

$preposition = array(" alongside "," amidst "," among ", " beside "," including ","  near ", " as well "," next to ", " within ");
shuffle($preposition);
$preposition_rand = array_slice($preposition,0, count($keywords_array)-1);

$description = $frontword_list ." ". implode("",array_map("join_list", $keywords_array, $preposition_rand));
echo $description;

echo "\n";
```

Output - randomly changing:
Magnificent car 1   alongside  car 2   amidst  car 3   next to  car 4   among  car 5   as well  car 5   including  car 6